# Swift textview from url

Tags: swift, textview

I want to fill my textview with a .txt file's content from an url.
Currently i have this but this is just does the trick locally but thats not what i really want 
Can someone help me to get the data load from an url?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myTextView.text = load(file: "proba.txt")

}

func load(file name:String) -> String {
    /*
     ez igy oksi de ez lokálisan tölti be és nekem az kevés
     */

    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "proba", ofType: "txt") {

        if let contents = try? String(contentsOfFile: path) {

            return contents

        } else {

            print("Error! - This file doesn't contain any text.")
        }

    } else {

        print("Error! - This file doesn't exist.")
    }

    return ""
}
```

Comment: you URL is from remote service?

Comment: I put it on my github repo: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SiposPtr/umszkiapp/master/proba.txt

Comment: because its free and i could edit it easily but if its not okay then i will move it to somewhere else

Comment: no problem, look my answer..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's simple, just copy and paste:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        let content = self.downloadContent()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.myTextView.text = content
        }
    }
}

func downloadContent() -> String {
    var data : Data!
    data = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SiposPtr/umszkiapp/master/proba.txt")!)
    if let data_str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        return data_str
    } else {
        return ""
    }
}
```